# Nuxt generated HTML and JavaScript does not work everywhere

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt to build a component library for use with the various CMSs that my company uses. Basically, I want to use the generated HTML to create reusable widgets for the CMS. The CMSs in question can't use Vue components directly because the client's admin area doesn't play well with Vue (for example, the inline editor in Kentico 12 does not work at all with Vue and our clients require this functionality).

Using Nuxt to build the component library works great as long as the components don't DO anything. However, if I want to create an accordion that has an @click event, it doesn't work when loaded into the CMS. I narrowed down the issue:

A) http://example.com/Accordions/
B) http://example.com/Accordions/index.html

Case A works fine. With Case B, the page loads but none of the scripts work. The events do not fire at all, and I'm getting the following error:

"DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method."

The Accordions component doesn't work on any page that is not http://example.com/Accordions/.

Nuxt is generating the Accordions/index.html page so I'm assuming it's connecting the route with the functionality in the JS, but I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, what to search for or how to fix it. I've been searching for hours. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What browser are you testing with and how is the site being served (`nuxt start` vs `nuxt build` + `nuxt start`)?

Comment: I'm using the latest Chrome. Everything works fine locally with nuxt start. I'm using nuxt generate to generate the static pages.